# How to enable html in AngularUI accordion-group content?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion

I am trying to display content in an accordion-group that potentially has html markup. The content is being retrieved from external sources. How do I do this?

You can see this at [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMc2CI) (content hard-coded for test purposes)

As you can see, the items show with markup not converted to links. How do I enable html markup?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found you're running into something new with 1.2.  There's some extra security/sanitization business wrapped in this $sce service.  It's news to me but here's the updated working plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/frmJgjmwFq1hg4haZxJR?p=preview

The key here was to inject $sce then us it like

```
$sce.trustAsHtml
```

On the strings to be trusted, then using ng-bind-html to get it to pass through the HTML without turning it into a string.

Comment: Thanks for your response, which is a useful first step (in my newbie process). I will need to find a way to apply trustAsHtml() to content retrieved dynamically - unlike the hard-coded example.

Comment: You should be able to inject $sce wherever you need it, since you need to apply it to some dynamic data your likely to want to encapsulate that functionality into a service and inject it like: angular.module("myApp",[]).service(function($sce){return {/*service definition here, iterate over returned data and run $sce.trustAsHtml to replace each element that will need to be trusted*/}});  Keep in mind this would allow cross site scripting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5l9lSnNMxg

Comment: I am not sure what data (array) I would iterate on in the service function - does it not need to be passed in as a parameter? It seems a filter may be appropriate here, but how do I get a reference/access to $sce inside the filter function?

Comment: I am still trying to get this to work - see http://plnkr.co/edit/bMc2CI - what have I done wrong?

Comment: You were just missing the use of ng-bind-html the inline interpolation won't be interpreted as HTML as far as I know.

Comment: No problem, if this answers your question hit the check mark to accept it to let others know this solution works.